# Adding tags/categories to posts in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking to add tags to my Blog app.

I wish for Posts to have none, one or many tags. For now, I want to restrict the choice of tags to 10 pre-defined tags.

Should I create a model:

```
   post_id, tag_name
   1, sport
   1, news
   1, fun
   2, sport
   3, news
```

Or a wider table:

```
   post_id, tag_sport, tag_special
   1,Yes,No,...
```

Or include the chosen tags within the post table:

```
   post_id, post_body, post_tags
   1, lorem ipsum, sport|news|fun
```

How would the form look?

```
   Free textbox separated by commas? Checkbox?
```

I know there are plugins and existing options available, but would like to be able to control the tags via a table. I have followed some tutorials but they do not provide a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem,watch [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging) may give you better idea

Comment: Completely agree. The simplest possible solutions is the one requiring less code on your side, and less maintenance. Use a precooked gem, follow instructions and live your life.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, and keeping with "the simplest thing that could possibly work", if you only have to deal with, say, 10 pre-defined tags then I might be inclined to go with a simple serialized field.

However, this entails additional effort and places unnecessary load on your database when you want to search for posts by tag (simplest is a LIKE query, which in most cases involves a table scan).

So, personally, even with a simple tagging system I will almost always end up with a `tags` table of just `id` and `name`, then a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between the tags and the taggable entities:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
```

And in `Tag`:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
```

Of course, this means having to write a migration to create the appropriate join table, something like:

```
class CreatePostsTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts_tags do |t|
      t.references :post, null: false
      t.references :tag, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This way the database schema is also kept in [normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms).

To search by tag, it reduces to something like:

```
Tag.find_by_name('news').posts
```

(In practice, you'll want a `Tag.named(name)` method that'll `strip.downcase` `name` for you.)

As for the form, again, the simplest thing I might end up with is just a plain text field, where tags are separated by commas (and therefore the comma character isn't a valid character in a tag name). Or, if you don't allow spaces in tag names, you can use the space as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a comnplete solution here. SO is not a code dispenser.

What you have here is a typical n to m relationship. A post may have many tags (the restriction of a max of 10 tags is irrelevant for this) - and a tag can be part of many posts.

n to m relations are modelled through the use of a 2 additional tables: 1 for the relating model (the tag) and one for saving the relationships.

This give you (assuming your post table is named posts)

Table `posts_tags` which looks like this:

```
id
post_id
tag_id
```

And a table `tags`:

```
id
tagname
```

The relation is then described in the models via `has_and_belongs_to_many`

If a post only can have one tag - you can simplify this with using just a 1 to many relation.

For the design and given the small number of tags, I would just use a bunch of checkboxes. But that is up to you. You will find examples for the visualisation of n:m with rails on the web.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be use `habtm` relation between books and tags.

```
   class < books
     has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
     validates :no_of_tags


     def no_of_tags
        if self.tags.length < 4 #your choiche
          false
        end
     end
   end


   class < tags
     has_and_belongs_to_many :books
   end
```

Plus create a table books_posts

this will solve your problem